# How to make https requests using a HAPI FHIR client

Tags: java, hapi

Is there any example of how make a HTTPS call with a hapi fhir client ?

```
FhirContext ctx = new FhirContext();
IGenericClient client = ctx.newRestfulGenericClient("https://fhirtest.uhn.ca/base");
```

By default the above code will not work as the server will require SSL authentication.

how do I add SSL authentication to the hapi client ??

Answer (score 0):

The next example shows how to connect to a FHIR server using https while using the HAPI FHIR client. Please be aware that this example accepts all certificates. To make it secure you should specify a truststore and a different hostname verifier.

```java
FhirContext ctx = new FhirContext();

KeyStore truststore = null;
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(truststore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();

HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE;
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, hostnameVerifier);

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory).build();
ctx.getRestfulClientFactory().setHttpClient(httpClient);

IGenericClient client = ctx.newRestfulGenericClient("https://fhirtest.uhn.ca/base");
```